# How to remove the Agile section from all view screens

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, greenhopper

We are doing a custom JIRA project now, for the view issues screen, we want to remove the Agile section (under the People and Dates section) on the right side only for one certain project. (Because for JIRA instance, greenhopper feature is enabled)

Anyone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this section should not be shown if GreenHopper is not enabled for this project. Check Administation | Plugins | GreenHopper, tab Enabled Projects.

You can remove this section completely by disabling "greenhopper-agile-issue-web-panel" module of the GreenHopper plugin (under Administration | Plugins | Manage Plugins menu, select GreenHopper and "show modules").

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Jira 6.4 Disable the following plugin

> System add-ons >
>   JIRA Agile Marketing Plugin